# Multiple tables for a single model in Sails.js?

Tags: model, sails.js, sails-postgresql

I currently have a website written in Perl, using [Mojolicious](http://mojolicious.org) and [Mojo::Pg](https://github.com/kraih/mojo-pg). One of the things it does is pull in and display data from my Ninja Block's temperature sensors. I have four tables in Postgres, `outdoor_temperature`, `outdoor_humidity`, and the same again for indoors. The tables look like this:

```
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers 
--------+---------+-----------
 time   | bigint  | not null
 value  | numeric | not null
 date   | date    | not null
```

Where `time` is an epoch value in milliseconds (one record per minute), `value` is the temperature or humidity, and `date` is just that (so every record for a given day has the same value in the `date` column).

I'm rewriting the site using Node and Sails.js, mostly just for the learning opportunity, and I'm kind of stuck on the best way to do things here. In its Perl incarnation, I have a single subroutine for each Ninja Block-related function (display the current temperatures for today, display the highest/lowest for a given day, etc.) and I pass in which location it's for (indoor or outdoor) and everything goes from there, like this:

```
sub current {
    my ( $self, $table ) = @_;
    return $self->pg->db->query( "select time, value from $table where time = (select max(time) from $table)" )->hash;
}
```

But with Sails/Waterline, it seems to be that a model consists of just one table. There's no joins between any of the tables in my Perl version, just some semi-complex SQL queries on each individual table that I can accomplish in Sails with `.query`, but I'm not sure how to retain this same setup under Sails without needing to duplicate a bunch of code when checking both the indoor and outdoor tables.

Or am I thinking about this totally wrongly and there's a significantly better way to accomplish it all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with a service that sits in between the controller and the model. The controller function looks like this (using the same example as above):

```
currentTemperature: function(req, res) {
    ninjaBlockService.getCurrentTemperature(req.param('location'), function(data) {
        return res.json(data);
    });
}
```

<strike>And the service function:</strike>

```
getCurrentTemperature: function(location, callback) {
    var query = "select time, value from " + location + "_temperature where time = (select max(time) from " + location + "_temperature)";

    var locations = {
        outdoor: function() {
            NinjaBlockOutdoorTemperature.query(query, function(err, results) {
                return callback(results.rows);
            });
        },
        indoor: function() {
            NinjaBlockIndoorTemperature.query(query, function(err, results) {
                return callback(results.rows);
            });
        }
    };

    locations[location]();
}
```

It could probably be a bit more elegant, but it's working nicely for me.

So as it turns out if you're using Waterline's PostgreSQL native `.query`, you don't even need multiple models for multiple tables. I've added a new model called `NinjaBlock` that has no attributes or anything, and can run my queries regardless of which table they're in. So the function above now looks like this instead:

```
getCurrentTemperature: function(location, callback) {
    var query = "select time, value from " + location + "_temperature where time = (select max(time) from " + location + "_temperature)";

    NinjaBlock.query(query, function(err, results) {
                return callback(results.rows);
    });
}
```

Simple!